# Modifying the Microstrategy SQL Generator

Tags: sql, infobright, microstrategy

I am using Microstrategy, and I am aware of the Freeform SQL Report functionality.  However, I'd like to change how Microstrategy generates its SQL.

Since I'm using Infobright, I'd like to use sub-selects instead of full joins, etc.  Example:

Query generated by Microstrategy:
    select b.colb,
    min(b.cold),
    sum(a.colb)
    from   tablea a 
    join tableb b
    on a.id = b.id
    group by b.colb

I'd like it to generate the following way:
    select b.colb,
    min(b.cold),
    sum(a.colb)
    from   (select id, sum(cold) from tablea a group by colb)
    join tableb b
    on a.id = b.id
    group by b.colb

Is it possible to modify the generator to take this type of approach as opposed to the current approach?  Or, must I use the freeform generator?

Answer (score 2):

In Report->Go to VLDB Properties->Sub Query Type->select 6 th option->where col 1 in (select s1.col1..) falling back to exists (Select col1, col2...) for multiple columns IN

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way MSTR generates SQL by changing the VLDB properties (at the report level or at the database instance level).

On the VLDB settings, I think you should be looking for the "Derived Table" option, on the "Intermediate Table Type"  inside the Tables folder, but have a look at the other options on the Tables folder and also the Query Optimizations folder.